# Wordpress wp-bootstrap-navwalker mobile menu not opening

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wp-nav-walker

I think there is something wrong with the js of my wordpress. I'm making a custom theme and want to use bootstrap navbar in it so i found wp-bootstrap-navwalker. And i got that working on another project im working on. I copied all the code and files into the new directory. But now the mobile hamburger menu won't open. And i don't understand why because the code is pretty much identical

Here is my functions.php

```
<?php
require_once get_template_directory() . '/inc/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php';

register_nav_menus([ 'primary' => 'Päävalikko']);

function pagename_assets() {
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_enqueue_style('boostrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '4,1,3', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_script('boostrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '4.1.3', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pagename_assets');
?>
```

Here is my header.php navbar code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-controls="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Toggle navigation', 'your-theme-slug' ); ?>">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location'  => 'primary',
                'depth'           => 1, // 1 = no dropdowns, 2 = with dropdowns.
                'container'       => 'div',
                'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                'container_id'    => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav mr-auto',
                'fallback_cb'     => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'          => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
            ) );
            ?>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I don't understand what is wrong because the installs of wordpress are the same version. Same bootstrap files in the same locations:

- assets

  - css

    - bootstrap.min.css
  - js
    -bootstrap.bundle.min.js
- inc

  - class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php
- footer.php
- front-page.php
- functions.php
- header.php
- index.php
- style.css

It just doesn't make any sense